# spring map optional query parameters to sql prepared statement

Tags: sql, spring, jdbc, parameters

I'm creating a REST API in Spring for a project.

The problem I'm facing is how to elegantly create a PreparedStatement with variable number of parameters.

For eg. I have a product collection and I'd have lots of query parameters

/accounts?categoryId=smth&order=asc&price=<1000&limit=10&offset=300

Problem is that these parameters may or may not be set.

Currently I have something that looks like this, but I haven't even started sanitizing for user input

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Address> getAll(@RequestParam Map<String, String> parameters) {
        return addressRepository.getAll(parameters);
}
```

Repository

```
@Override
public List<Address> getAll(Map<String, String> parameters) {
    StringBuilder conditions = new StringBuilder();
    List<Object> parameterValues = new ArrayList<Object>();
    for(String key : parameters.keySet()) {
        if(allowedParameters.containsKey(key) && !key.equals("limit") && !key.equals("offset")) {
            conditions.append(allowedParameters.get(key));
            parameterValues.add(parameters.get(key));
        }
    }
    int limit = Pagination.DEFAULT_LIMIT_INT;
    int offset = Pagination.DEFAULT_OFFSET_INT;
    if(parameters.containsKey("limit"))
        limit = Pagination.sanitizeLimit(Integer.parseInt(parameters.get("limit")));
    if(parameters.containsKey("offset"))
        offset = Pagination.sanitizeOffset(Integer.parseInt(parameters.get("offset")));
    if(conditions.length() != 0) {
        conditions.insert(0, "WHERE ");
        int index = conditions.indexOf("? ");
        int lastIndex = conditions.lastIndexOf("? ");
        while(index != lastIndex) {
            conditions.insert(index + 2, "AND ");
            index = conditions.indexOf("? ", index + 1);
            lastIndex = conditions.lastIndexOf("? ");
        }
    }
    parameterValues.add(limit);
    parameterValues.add(offset);
    String base = "SELECT * FROM ADDRESSES INNER JOIN (SELECT ID FROM ADDRESSES " + conditions.toString() + "LIMIT ? OFFSET ?) AS RESULTS USING (ID)";
    System.out.println(base);
    return jdbc.query(base, parameterValues.toArray(), new AddressRowMapper());
}
```

Can I improve this? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

I found the above code hard to maintain since it has complex logic to build the where clause. Spring's [NamedParameterJdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html) could be used to simplify the logic. Follow [this](http://www.dineshonjava.com/2012/12/using-namedparameterjdbctemplate-in.html#.VIKnzfnLcXU) link for having a look at a basic example on NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Here's how the new code should look like

```
    public List<Address> getAll(Map<String, String> parameters) {
        Map<String, Object> namedParameters = new HashMap<>();
        for(String key : parameters.keySet()) {
            if(allowedParameters.contains(key)) {
                namedParameters.put(key, parameters.get(key));
            }
        }

        String sqlQuery = buildQuery(namedParameters);

        NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(null /* your data source object */);
        return template.query(sqlQuery, namedParameters, new AddressRowMapper());
    }

    private String buildQuery(Map<String, Object> namedParameters) {
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM ADDRESSES INNER JOIN (SELECT ID FROM ADDRESSES ";
        if(!(namedParameters.isEmpty())) {
            String whereClause = "WHERE ";
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> param : namedParameters.entrySet()) {
                whereClause += param.getKey() + " = :" + param.getValue();
            }

            selectQuery += whereClause;
        }
        return selectQuery + " ) AS RESULTS USING (ID)";
    }
```

Comment: another problem with this approach is that I loose type safety on parameters. Being a collection resource, I must paginate. Every time I query the parameter map I would have to check whether it's LIMIT or OFFSET and cast the parameter value to long. I would have to have a set of rules attached to each allowed parameter. Am I making this too complex?

Comment: Yes I think you are making it complex :). You lost type safety in the original approach too and thats mainly because you receive a Map<String, String> as parameters. For this you could try @QueryParam but the namedParameters map would still have to be Map<String, Object>. If you think of making the map type safe, you would lose on writing generic code that works for all parameters.

Answer (score 0):

After some thinking I decided type safety is important and I decided to use the following style throughout the API.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Address> getAll(@RequestParam(value = "cityId", required = false) Long cityId,
                            @RequestParam(value = "accountId", required = false) Long accountId,
                            @RequestParam(value = "zipCode", required = false) String zipCode,
                            @RequestParam(value = "limit", defaultValue = Pagination.DEFAULT_LIMIT_STRING) Integer limit,
                            @RequestParam(value = "offset", defaultValue = Pagination.DEFAULT_OFFSET_STRING) Integer offset) {
    Map<String, Object> sanitizedParameters = AddressParameterSanitizer.sanitize(accountId, cityId, zipCode, limit, offset);
    return addressRepository.getAll(sanitizedParameters);
}
```

Parameter sanitation

```
public static Map<String, Object> sanitize(Long accountId, Long cityId, String zipCode, Integer limit, Integer offset) {
    Map<String, Object> sanitizedParameters = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>(5);

    if(accountId != null) {
        if (accountId < 1) throw new InvalidQueryParameterValueException(ExceptionMessage.INVALID_ID);
        else sanitizedParameters.put("ACCOUNT_ID = ? ", accountId);
    }

    if(cityId != null) {
        if (cityId < 1) throw new InvalidQueryParameterValueException(ExceptionMessage.INVALID_ID);
        else sanitizedParameters.put("CITY_ID = ? ", cityId);
    }

    if(zipCode != null) {
        if (!zipCode.matches("[0-9]+")) throw new InvalidQueryParameterValueException(ExceptionMessage.INVALID_ZIP_CODE);
        else sanitizedParameters.put("ZIP_CODE = ? ", zipCode);
    }

    if (limit < 1 || limit > Pagination.MAX_LIMIT_INT) throw new InvalidQueryParameterValueException(ExceptionMessage.INVALID_LIMIT);
    else sanitizedParameters.put("LIMIT ? ", Pagination.sanitizeLimit(limit));

    if(offset < 0) throw new InvalidQueryParameterValueException(ExceptionMessage.INVALID_OFFSET);
    else sanitizedParameters.put("OFFSET ?", Pagination.sanitizeOffset(offset));

    return sanitizedParameters;
}
```

SQL Query String builder

```
public static String buildQuery(Tables table, Map<String, Object> sanitizedParameters) {
    String tableName = table.name();
    String baseQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " INNER JOIN (SELECT ID FROM " + tableName;
    String whereClause = " ";
    if(sanitizedParameters.size() > 2) {
        whereClause += "WHERE ";
    }
    if(!sanitizedParameters.isEmpty()) {
        for(String key : sanitizedParameters.keySet()) {
            whereClause += key;
        }
        baseQuery += whereClause;
    }
    return baseQuery + ") AS RESULTS USING (ID)";
}
```

Repository:

```
@Override
public List<Address> getAll(Map<String, Object> sanitizedParameters) {
    String sqlQuery = CollectionQueryBuilder.buildQuery(Tables.ADDRESSES, sanitizedParameters);
    return jdbc.query(sqlQuery, sanitizedParameters.values().toArray(), new AddressRowMapper());
}
```